# Is there a shortcut for adding title of linked-questions in comments?

Tags: support, comments, hyperlinks

When I want to add a link in a comment, I always do the following:

1. Copy the question's URL, paste it:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39960679/what-is-the-purpose-of-row-in-bootstrap
```

2. Copy the question's title, paste it:

```
What is the purpose of .row in Bootstrap?
```

3. Format the whole thing to have:

```
[What is the purpose of .row in Bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39960679/what-is-the-purpose-of-row-in-bootstrap)
```

4. Result: [What is the purpose of .row in Bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39960679/what-is-the-purpose-of-row-in-bootstrap)

---

I'm pretty sure there is a shorter way to do the following, as in answer we just have to copy/paste the URL:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39960679/what-is-the-purpose-of-row-in-bootstrap
```

[What is the purpose of .row in Bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39960679/what-is-the-purpose-of-row-in-bootstrap)

As we have `[answer]` and `[ask]` links, I guess there is something similar for others SO links. I didn't find anything in [Markdown editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting). Could you help me?

Comment: Yes, use the [SE Comment Link Helper](//stackapps.com/q/2378).